# Reading int from command line returning nil swift toInt()

Tags: swift

Working on learning swift - reading from command line just fine, however when I try to convert to an int I keep getting nil

```
import Foundation
func getInput() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    var inputString = NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return inputString!
}

var test = getInput()
println(test)
var testInt = test.toInt()
println(testInt)
```

Yields the output

```
123
123

nil
```

It looks like there is an extra newline in there from reading from command line - so I've tried replacing whitespace to no avail

```
test = getInput().stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

Which gives the same output. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think a newline is considered whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
test = getInput().stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```